# Eclipse + Maven -> eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I want to set up maven in eclipse. If I set the option

```
-vm 
C:\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

in the eclipse.ini, my eclipse is not starting anymore. The path is definitely correct and I saw the entry like this on different sources on the internet. My complete configuration looks like that:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-vm 
C:\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: All content after `-vmargs` are vm argument (like -Xmx, -Dxxx etc). Your `-vm` should be inserted before this, because this is not vm argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the 2 lines :

`-vm`

`C:\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe`

before the `-vmargs` option.

This is because anything after the `-vmargs` is taken as arguments.

Comment: Thanks that works! I did not know that the order matters until now :)